# Java using Lists to store Lists

Tags: java, list, for-loop, store

I've tried to create a program with 2 lists; list1 (`List<Integer>`), that would constantly add new values, and list2 (`List<List<Integer>>`), that would store values of list1. I've started with this:

```
int x=1;
    while(x<=10)
    {
        list1.add(x);
        System.out.println(list1);
        x++;
    }
```

And output was just like i thought;

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

then I've changed `System.out.println(list1);` to `list2.add(list1);` and then included an enchanced for loop;

```
        for(List<Integer> y:list2)
    {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
```

But instead of the output like before, it said:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Like it just repeated the last state of list1 10 times!
Do you know, what is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you add the integers to the **same** `List` object at each iteration, and then add this list object to your list of list object.

Think of a situation like this :

[image]
One workaround could be :

```
int x=1;
while(x <= 10){
   l1 = new ArrayList<>(l1);//create a new list object with values of the old one
   l1.add(x);
   l2.add(l1);
   x++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The lists are most likely referencing the same `List` object. To avoid this, you want to add a `new List<Integer>` each iteration.

You could do something like this

```
int x = 1;
while (x <= 10) {

    int y = 1;
    while (y <= x) {
        List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
        list.add(y);
        y++;
    }
    y = 1;
    list2.add(list);
}

for (List<Integer> list: list2){
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lists are most likely referencing the same List object,after  you add list1 to list2,you changed list1.so list1 in list2 also changed.